# What are those black dots in my water?

Tags: water, refrigerator, filter

I recently changed my water filter in my fridge after 3 years (I know, gross). The directions said to run at least 20 cups of water through the dispenser afterwards to clear out air bubbles. I have run about 20 gallons through, and I'm still getting little black particles in the water.  Is this charcoal, from the filter, and safe to drink, or is it something else?

Comment: Almost certainly charcoal. Did you soak the filter before installing it?

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through this too.  If it sinking black particles then that is charcoal/carbon.  That is from your filter.  You can drink/digest it just fine but if that makes you squirmy then take the filter back.  Honestly there seems to be something a little off about your filter but at the same time the particles aren't necessarily harmful.

Comment: Agreed - probably charcoal, but after 20 gallons it should stop.